# Make a discord.py bot wait for a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a tictactoe command in my bot, and I want to make it so that after player 1 has used the tictactoe command, it will wait for player 2 to do the tictactoe command, but I want it to timeout after 30 seconds of no tictactoe command. Here's my code for the tictactoe command:

```
@commands.command(aliases=['ristinolla', 'ttt', 'rn'])
async def tictactoe(ctx, x, y):
    lang = await ctx.bot.get_lang(ctx)
    try:
        turn = ctx.bot.players[ctx.channel.id][2]
        X = ctx.bot.players[ctx.channel.id][0]
        O = ctx.bot.players[ctx.channel.id][1]
        if ctx.author.id != turn:
            if lang == "fi":
                await ctx.send("❌ **|** Ei ole sinun vuorosi")
            else:
                await ctx.send("❌ **|** It is not your turn")
        elif x[0] not in ctx.bot.x and y[0] not in ctx.bot.y:
            await ctx.send("Usage:\n{}tictactoe <top/middle/bottom> <left/middle/right>".format(bot.prefix))
        else:
            if turn == X:
                piece = "X"
            else:
                piece = "O"
            lauta = ctx.bot.boards[ctx.channel.id]
            if lauta[int(ctx.bot.x[str(x[0])])][int(ctx.bot.y[str(y[0])])] != " ":
                if lang == "fi":
                    await ctx.send("❌ **|** Paikka varattu, kokeile toista paikkaa")
                else:
                    await ctx.send("❌ **|** Spot is already taken, try another spot")
                return

            lauta[int(ctx.bot.x[str(x[0])])][int(ctx.bot.y[str(y[0])])] = piece
            await ctx.send(await ctx.bot.lautavisual(lauta))
            #wincheck
            if (lauta[0] == [piece, piece, piece]
            or lauta[1] == [piece, piece, piece]
            or lauta[2] == [piece, piece, piece]
            or lauta[0][0] == piece and lauta[1][1] == piece and lauta[2][2] == piece
            or lauta[0][2] == piece and lauta[1][1] == piece and lauta[2][0] == piece
            or lauta[0][0] == piece and lauta[1][0] == piece and lauta[2][0] == piece
            or lauta[0][1] == piece and lauta[1][1] == piece and lauta[2][1] == piece
            or lauta[0][2] == piece and lauta[1][2] == piece and lauta[2][2] == piece):
                if lang == "fi":
                    await ctx.send(" **|** {} on voittanut!".format(ctx.author.mention))
                else:
                    await ctx.send(" **|** {} has won!".format(ctx.author.mention))
                ctx.bot.boards.pop(ctx.channel.id)
                ctx.bot.players.pop(ctx.channel.id)
                return
            elif (lauta[0][0] != " "
            and lauta[0][1] != " "
            and lauta[0][2] != " "
            and lauta[1][0] != " "
            and lauta[1][1] != " "
            and lauta[1][2] != " "
            and lauta[2][0] != " "
            and lauta[2][1] != " "
            and lauta[2][2] != " "):
                if lang == "fi":
                    await ctx.send(" **|** Tasapeli!")
                else:
                    await ctx.send(" **|** Tie!")
                ctx.bot.boards.pop(ctx.channel.id)
                ctx.bot.players.pop(ctx.channel.id)
                return
            else:
                if turn == X:
                    ctx.bot.players[ctx.channel.id][2] = O
                else:
                    ctx.bot.players[ctx.channel.id][2] = X
                if lang == "fi":
                    await ctx.send(" **|** <@{}>, nyt on sinun vuorosi".format(ctx.bot.players[ctx.guild.id][2]))
                else:
                    await ctx.send(" **|** <@{}>, it is now your turn".format(ctx.bot.players[ctx.guild.id][2]))
```

Comment: please share some lines of your code for others to understand

Comment: added the code, sorry my bad

Comment: Thanks and i updated my answer so you can try using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: You cannot copy paste this code in your code. This is just to give you an idea

```py
  def check(m: discord.Message): 
        return m.author.id==turn.id and m.content.startswith("{your prefix}tictactoe")


  try:
      
        msg = await bot.wait_for(event = 'message', check = check, timeout = 30.0)
        return 
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, you didn't play in 30 seconds..")
        return
  else:
        #your code to place the piece
```

Reference:[GIST TO GET MESSAGES IN LIMITED TIME](https://gist.github.com/Soheab/e73ab6f66881ee4102be37815da3a24e)

Comment: wouldn't this just make it so that if "turn.id" sends any message, the timer ends? I'm trying to make it so that the other player has to use the tictactoe command, and if the command works, it ends the timer

Comment: you can try making `return m.author.id==turn.id` to  `return m.author.id==turn.id and m.content.startswith("{your prefix}tictactoe")`

Comment: that would work, except it would end the timer even if the command didn't necessarily work

Comment: yep, that would give the user a time limit instead of taking a long time to play. If the user doesn't play then it would just return